# Exception on showing a splash screeen in C#

Tags: c#

**Background**: I got code for a desktop application written by a freelancer a few months back. The freelancer has since closed his account. For the past few days, I've been trying to learn and decipher the code already written. I'm basically a C# newbie and am tutoring myself with a Udemy C# lesson.

**Problem**: When the application starts, it shows a splash screen. I can run the application in Release mode where the splash screen displays properly. But in the Debug mode with the Common Language Runtime Exceptions ticked in the settings, I get an Exception. Details are below.

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException occurred
  HResult=-2146233040
  Message=Thread was being aborted.
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at CamCon.MainForm.StartSplash() in E:\Freelance\CamArd\App_C# (2020.03.04)\CamCon\MainForm.cs:line 289
  InnerException:
```

These are the relevant snippets of code:

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //show splash screen for 2.5seconds
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartSplash));
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(2500);
        t.Abort();
    }
```

And:

```
    private void StartSplash()
    {
        Application.Run(new SplashForm()); // Exception happens here. This is MainForm.cs:line 289
    }
```

And:

```
    namespace CameraControl
    {
        partial class SplashForm
        {
            private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && (components != null))
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

            #region Windows Form Designer generated code

            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
                this.SuspendLayout();
                // 
                // pictureBox1
                // 
                this.pictureBox1.Image = global::CameraControl.Properties.Resources.splash;
                this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
                this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
                this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(600, 400);
                this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
                // 
                // SplashForm
                // 
                this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
                this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(600, 400);
                this.ControlBox = false;
                this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
                this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
                this.Name = "SplashForm";
                this.ShowIcon = false;
                this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
                this.Text = "SplashForm";
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
                this.ResumeLayout(false);

            }

            #endregion

            private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        }
    }
```

**Request**: Can anyone please help and suggest what I should be looking at, to correct this exception; so that it does not come back to bite me elsewhere in the application (and I'm having some issues elsewhere too, but that's for later)?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

.NET has a built-in `SplashScreen` class that you can use.  Documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen?view=netframework-4.8).

Regarding the exception, that's by design.  You are calling `Thread.Abort` and that operates by literally throwing a `ThreadAbortException`.  Not a good thing.

Using `Thread.Abort` is a bad design in almost all cases for a variety of reasons I won't go into.  But at face value you can see that simply throwing an exception is not a clean way to stop a thread.